# The element type future<List<Data>> can not be assign to the list type of Future<Data>

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am trying to use `Future.wait` on FutureBuilder so this is my code:

```
child: SafeArea(
  child: FutureBuilder<List<ActiveTools.Data>>(
    future: Future.wait([
      MyToolsProvider()
          .getChannelMe("df6b88b6-f47d-****"),
    ]),
    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<List<ActiveTools.Data>> dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
```

In `MyToolsProvider().getChannelMe` method i return `Future<List<ActiveTools.Data>>` :

```
import 'package:mobile_iotel/models/active_tools_model.dart'as ActiveTools;


  Future<List<ActiveTools.Data>> getChannelMe(String auth) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> header = {
      'Content-Type': "application/json",...
    };

    try {
      var result = await NetworkCLient()
          .getRequest(url: '$URL/api/me', header: header);
      debugPrint('result is $result');
      if (result != null) {
        var programsByActiveToolsModel =
            ActiveTools.ProgramsByActiveToolsModel.fromJson(result);
        if (programsByActiveToolsModel.responseCode == 200) {
          return programsByActiveToolsModel.data;
        } else
          return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('catch is $e');
    }
  }
```

but in `Future.wait` i got this error :

[image]

> The element type future> can not be assign to the list type of Future

My method return `List<ActiveTools.Data>` and why i got this error?

Comment: why do you use Future.wait ??

Comment: Because i have 2 future. one of them fetch data from service and store data to database and other fetch data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ActiveTools.Data` to `List<dynamic>` and also get the first element in `dataSnapshot.data`, you should find what you expected `List<ActiveTools.Data>`.

```
child: SafeArea(
  child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>( // You might want to use List<List<ActiveTools.Data>>
    future: Future.wait([
      MyToolsProvider()
          .getChannelMe("df6b88b6-f47d-****"),
    ]),
    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      //...omit
      List<ActiveTools.Data> datas = dataSnapshot.data[0];
```

It seems that you don't have two future in the provided code, so you don't need to use `Future.wait` as @Darish said. For more about [Future.wait](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html), please read the documentation.